# How to pass a resource id to a custom view and indicate for which child view to use it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have a custom view implemented in Java that is a vertical layout with 4 child views.
I would like to be able to pass a configuration for each child view via a method in the custom view.
Let's assume I just want to pass a different color id per view e.g. for child 1 use `R.color.white` and for child 2 use `R.color.red` etc
How could I pass this information to the custom view? The following would work:

```
public void configure(int color1, int color2, int color3, int color4)
```

but the problem with that is that I would prefer a way that the caller of the method indicates which color is for which child (1,2,3,4) instead of passing the colors fixed in the method call

Comment: An array of `int[]` colors?

Comment: You can do something like this... `configure(0xFF000, -1, 0x00FFFF)` to set child 1 and 3, but not 2. You would detected the presence of `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to allow callers to configure individual children, I recommend exposing individual methods for each child:

```
public void configureChild1(int color)
public void configureChild2(int color)
...
```

If you want just a single "dynamic" method, you will have to accept something like a `Map` from position to color, or a vararg `Pair` of position and color:

```
public void configure(Map<Integer, Integer> positionsToColors)
public void configure(Pair<Integer, Integer> ... positionAndColors)
```

The downside for these is that there's no compile-time way of knowing that the passed-in positions are valid.

Comment: My concern with this is that the function caller has to assume that there is a child 1,2, etc. I was wondering if there was another way to describe that